# Angular/Jasmin promise unit test not working

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

The following Angular controller works fine:

```
angular.module("mymodule", [])

.service('svc', function($q) {
    this.call = function() {
        return $q.when(3);
    };
  })

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,svc) {
    svc.call() 
       .then(function successCallback(response) {
           $scope.var1 = response;
           console.log($scope.var1);
       });

});
```

However the related Jasmin unit test returns an error:

```
describe('Testing a Controller that uses a Promise', function () {
  var $scope;
  var $q;
  var deferred;

  beforeEach(module('mymodule'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_, _$q_, svc) {
    $q = _$q_;
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    deferred = _$q_.defer();
    spyOn(svc, 'call').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

    $controller('MainCtrl', { 
      $scope: $scope, 
      svc: svc
    });
  }));

  it('should resolve promise', function () {
    deferred.resolve(11);
    $scope.$apply();
    expect($scope.var1).toBe(11);
  });
```

The error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'svc.call()
>                      .then(function successCallback(response) {
>                              $scope.var1 = response;
>                              console.log($scope.var1);
>                      })') in test/cookbook2.js (line 11)

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

PLUNK: http://plnkr.co/edit/j8J8J31ver1IE3fl6GyY?p=preview

Comment: It is not clear how the code above can throw `undefined is not a constructor`. A working plunk that can replicate the issue would help. Any way, what's the point of spying on `svc` methods here? The whole idea of  unit testing is to isolate the error in particular unit. From this spec you cannot tell if the error was caused by controller or service unit.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to inject whatever svc is and it does not exist. Can you post your test config and the svc service/controller/whatever it is?

Comment: @init fail that's all the code I have, do I need to define an svc service in addition to what I have in the unit test?

Comment: @estus I added a PLUNK to the question, however it works fine, the only difference with my environment is that I'm running the test under grunt/karma

Comment: The setup is wrong (it is `angular-mocks.js`, not `angular-mock.js`). But the rest is fine. As you can see, it doesn't have this error, and afaik there are no conditions for this piece of code that could create `undefined is not a constructor` error. If `svc` wouldn't exist (as it was proposed above), there would be injector error, and controller wouldn't run at all. Any way, testing strategy where `svc` is existing `svc` service is faulty, I would suggest to not use it and inject totally mocked object to `$controller`. It may or may not fix the problem but will be the right thing to do here.

Comment: I found the problem, there was a conflict with another controller with the same name, that's why the plunk is working.